# Using recursion to modify JSON

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, recursion

I am using **AngularJS** template to show a **JSON** as a list/tree structure.

My **JSON** depth is unknown. In most of the cases my code works. There is just one case I have encountered so far that does not work.

My JSON sample:

```
[
   {
      "type":"image",
      "bitmapname":{
         "text":"Image_12.bmp"
      },
      "command":[
         {
            "type":"close",
            "text":"1234"
         },
         {
            "type":"place",
            "text":"company"
         },
         {
            "type":"key",
            "key": "Tab"
         },
         {
            "type":"keyboard",
            "text":"welcome",
            "command": [
               {
                  "type":"open",
                  "text":"1234"
               },
               {
                  "type":"home",
                  "text":"company"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "type":"image",
      "bitmapname":{
         "text":"image_14.bmp"
      },
      "command":{
         "type":"move",
         "text":"right"
      }
   }
]
```

The output is below:

[image]

AngularJS code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="xml.html">
    <!-- XML is coming from controller as a JSON shown in my sample -->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in XML">

            [[ item["type"] ]]

            <div ng-include=" 'xml.html' " 
                onload="XML = item.command">
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

</script>

<div ng-include=" 'xml.html' ">
```

As you may noticed last list item is empty because that `"command"` is **not an Array**

I am trying to create a recursive function that will go through the JSON and create arrays on one element `"command": [{...}]` in places where I have `"command": {...}`

Can anyone suggest a solution that will convert the object to array of object wherever I have length-one object?

**NOTE**

I have no control over JSON being sent from Django backed. Python is using `xmltodict` extension to convert XML to Dictionary. Whenever XML tags have no children it does not create a list. It only creates a dictionary.

Comment: Can you tell us why your JSON isn't consistently using an array for the `.command` properties? The best solution here would be to start off with a consistent data format and not to find workarounds for an inconsistent one.

Comment: The JSON is being created from XML. And the python extension that converts the XML into JSON does not create an array when "command " tag in the XML has no children

Comment: I've run into similar issues when using automatic XML -> JSON serialization. I think a good solution would be to use a data structure-aware approach to serializing the data, but I've added an answer with the workaround you're requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very generic approach, but should work for your requirement:

```
function fixCommands(values) {
    values.filter(function (v) {
        return 'command' in v;
    })
    .forEach(function (v) {
        if(v.command.constructor === Array) {
            fixCommands(v.command);
        } else {
            v.command = [v.command];
        }
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/drbL2esr/)

Comment: Tnx JLRishe, I will let you know once I check this out

Answer (score 0):

You can check the first item that is it object or no if it was an object you can do a loop on it otherwise it's in other type that you have mentioned at top.for example

```
if(arr[i].command.length===undefined) -> so is string part
else -> is array part
```